# Swift Use Alamofire the same way SwiftHTTP does challenge authentication

Tags: swift, ssl, proxy, alamofire

How can I translate this code below using SwiftHTTP library, to Alamofire.  I am having a lot of issues getting through my internal proxy and ssl site. Here is he code below that works with SwiftHTTP

```
do {
    let opt = try HTTP.GET("https//site here")
    //the auth closures will continually be called until a successful auth or rejection
    var attempted = false
    opt.auth = { challenge in
        if !attempted {
            attempted = true
            return URLCredential(user: "user", password: "password", persistence: .forSession)
        }
        return nil //auth failed, nil causes the request to be properly cancelled.
    }
    opt.start { response in
        let json = JSON(response.description)
        print("We made it \(json)")
    }
} catch let error {
    print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
}
```

I have tried this with alamofire but I get a error code -999.  I have searched stackoverflow and github for answers, but none are clear to help. Here is what I tried.

```
var Manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {

    // Create the server trust policies
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "mydomain": .disableEvaluation
    ]

    // Create custom manager
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )

    return manager
}()

Manager.request(url!, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {

    case .success(let value):
        let json = JSON(value)
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This is the error I get.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

I have found the reason [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/157) but it doesn't help me get the code to work

Comment: You are sending just a get request to you URL. But you are not sending anything in the headers as parameters of the request function. For instance a username & a password or a token in the header.

Comment: @KeghamK. Thanks for helping I forgot the mention in my post.   I have tried adding .authentication(username: user, password: password) right after .validate().  Still didn't work I got the same error

Comment: This is how i call Alamofire request i add my authentication in the header. And add also the URLEncoding type. `Alamofire.request(route!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header)`
The header variable is off `HTTPHeaders` type where i add my authentication tokens in it ect..